# How is a double entry in Yaml parsed by ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have been asked to investigate performance problems in an ElasticSearch cluster, and have come across the following configuration:

```
indices:
  breaker:
    fielddata:
      limit: 50%
    fielddata:
      cache:
        expire: 15m
        size: 40%
    memory:
      index_buffer_size: 50%
```

Note that **there are two fielddata entries**.

What happens to the `fielddata.limit`, `fielddata.cache.expire` and `fielddata.cache.size` settings in the above scenario, compared with the following scenario which seems more logical to me?

```
indices:
  breaker:
    fielddata:
      limit: 50%
      cache:
        expire: 15m
        size: 40%
    memory:
      index_buffer_size: 50%
```

For example could the `fielddata.limit` field be lost by the fact that there is a second declaration of the `fielddata` level?

Answer (score 1):

[Relevant section](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#key//) in YAML spec:

> The content of a mapping node is an unordered set of key: value node pairs, with the restriction that each of the keys is unique.

Therefore, the YAML you posted is simply illegal and a compliant loader must stop with an error - however, since node equality is non-trivial, it is not implemented in the YAML implementation used in ElasticSearch (SnakeYAML), which also has an [open issue](https://code.google.com/archive/p/snakeyaml/issues/199) concerning duplicate keys.

Since ElasticSearch seems to allow duplicate keys, it fails to comply to the YAML spec. This is a bad thing and I advice to open an issue for it. More importantly, the ElasticSearch behavior cannot be deduced from the YAML implementation used. It has a [history](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/13079) for duplicate keys and there is a [statement](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-2-3-1-didnt-start-in-case-of-duplicate-variables-in-elasticsearch-yml/53091) from one of the devs:

> In addition, the next major version of elasticsearch will have strict setting parsing and return an error on start up if this happens.

To sum up: ElasticSearch not throwing an error for duplicate keys is a known shortcoming and will be fixed in the next major release. Therefore, current behavior is unintended and should not be used. According to the linked bug, the values of the *last* value for the duplicate key wins and the previous ones will be discarded. No merging of the child mappings will happen.